# Editor user only allow to post on certain categories

Tags: menus

I created user "editor", how do I set certain category for the editor user to post to?

I have many categories in my website, but I just want the editor user to be able to post on some categories that allowed.

Answer (score -1):

I found the plugin, "restrict categories".